If $A \vec{x} \preceq \vec{b}$ is infeasible with $A \in \mathbb{R}^{500 \times 100}$, show at most $101$ equations are infeasible.

Consider the following system of equations with a given matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{500 \times 100}$ and a given $\vec{b} \in \mathbb{R}^{500}$ (where $\preceq$ denotes component-wise inequality):
\begin{gather*}
  A \vec{x} \preceq \vec{b} \\
\end{gather*}
Equivalently, this system can be restated as $500$ equations of the following form, where $\vec{a}_i \in \mathbb{R}^{100}$ are the vectors corresponding to the $500$ rows of $A$:
\begin{gather*}
  {\langle \vec{a}_i, \vec{x} \rangle} \le \vec{b}_i, \qquad i = 1, \ldots, 500 \\
\end{gather*}
Show that there must be a subset of at most $101$ equations of the form ${\langle \vec{a}_i, \vec{x} \rangle} \le \vec{b}_i$ which are not feasible.

Since there exists no solution $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{100}$ that satisfies this system, then by the theorem of alternatives for linear inequalities, there must be a certificate of infeasibility $\vec{z} \in \mathbb{R}^{500}$ such that $\vec{z} \succeq \vec{0}$, $A^T \vec{z} = \vec{0}$, and ${\langle \vec{b}, \vec{z} \rangle} < 0$.
From here, I'm stuck.

There's an answer here that required some cleaning up, but is a valid proof of what you're trying to prove here.
